# Error when trying to import module from different folder

Tags: python

I have the following directory structure:

```
foo.py
│
└─── foodir/
    │
    └─── foofunc1.py
    │
    └─── foofunc2.py
```

I have a file `foo.py` that I'm trying to run that imports a function `func1` from `foofunc1.py` that relies on an import `func2` from `foofunc2.py`.

In `foo.py`, I import the function with `from foodir.foofunc1 import func1`. In `foofunc1.py`, `func2` is imported with `from foofunc2 import func2`.

When I run `foo.py` from the root directory, python complains that it can't find the module `foofunc2`. I realize that I could change the import statement to `from foodir.foofunc2 import func2`, but what if I need to run a script from inside `foodir`? I would like to avoid a case where I need to change all the import statements in a particular file just because I'm running it from a different location.

Comment: `from foofunc2 import func2` -> make that `from .foofunc2 import func2`. Note the leading dot: that makes it an intra-package relative import. You may have to add an empty `__init__.py` file inside the foodir folder.

Comment: "but what if I need to run a script from inside foodir?" That is bad practice: don't run a script from inside a package. Just make sure your package is either installed, or you have set your PYTHONPATH environment variable set to point to the directoy *above* foodir, then run the script externally. A "script" inside a package is really a module, and should be imported.

Comment: @9769953 it works when I run it from the root directory, but when I try to run from the inside `foodir`, I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

Comment: As per my second comment: it is really a bad idea to run the script from inside a package. You may not call it a package, but you've gathered two modules inside a directory, essentially making it a package. So run the script outside of that directory, and make sure Python can find the directory + two modules (also as per my second comment).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. How can I set PYTHONPATH to point to my root dir? Using `sys.path.append`?

Comment: No, set it in the environment. This depends on your operating system, and the shell (or IDE) you are using.